# Call custom transition animator using a programmatically created segue IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue, custom-transition

the project I am working on needs to have a custom transition between two view controllers. I have setup and implemented UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate by overriding the method like:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                              animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                           fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                             toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
   //Creation of animation
   id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning> animationController;
   MyAnimator *animator = [[MyAnimator alloc] init];
   animator.appearing = YES;
   animationController = animator;
   return animator
}
```

And I have setup MyAnimator subclass to correctly implement UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning by overriding the method:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    //custom transition animation
}
```

The segue which I using to trigger this animation transition is created and called programmatically, like:

```
UIStoryboardSegue *segue = [[UIStoryboardSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"showCardDetail" source:self destination:vc];
[self prepareForSegue:segue sender:self];
[segue perform];
```

Reason of creating segue programmatically: I have from(transition from) and to(transition to) view controllers in separate storyboards.

Problem / Question:
I have seen many examples, all handle the custom transition using a storyboard segue like:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"storyboardSegue-id" sender:self]
```

How should i define in the method *-perform* for segue created programmatically above so that the custom transition takes place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a custom segue to do what you're trying to do. In fact, since you have your 2 controllers in separate storyboards, you shouldn't use a segue at all. Just instantiate your destination view controller, and use pushViewController:animated: to initiate the transition. Your first view controller should be the delegate of the navigation controller, so the delegate method you show at the top of your question gets called.

Answer (score 0):

In `navigationControllerAnimationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:` you can adjust source and destination viewControllers and based on this types you will see desired animation. You do not need to use `prepareForSegue:` here.